# Add remove button to options in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I try to add remove button to options in select2 but when I click on button it doesn't work;
My code

```
<select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#mySelect').select2({
        tags: true,
        tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
        templateResult: formatOption
      });

      function formatOption(option) {
        if (!option.id) {
          return option.text;
        }

        var $option = $(
          '<span>' + option.text + '<span class="remove-button" onclick="removeItem(\'' + option.id + '\')">Remove</span></span>'
        );

        return $option;
      }

      window.removeItem = function(itemId) {
        $('#mySelect').find('option[value="' + itemId + '"]').remove();
        $('#mySelect').trigger('change');
      };
    });
  </script>
```

Its show the remove button but when I click on it it just select the option and not delete the option.

Comment: Seems to work fine in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7xbmepa4/1/). Consider providing more code in your example to reproduce the undesired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should catch the select2:selecting event first, then try to find which DOM element was clicked, located at "event.params.args.originalEvent.target", and if it has “remove-button” class, then simply call event.preventDefault(), after that continue how do you want.

Here complete solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#mySelect').select2({
        tags: true,
        tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
        templateResult: formatOption
      });

      function formatOption(option) {
        if (!option.id) {
          return option.text;
        }

       var $option = $(
          '<span>' + option.text + '<span class="remove-button" data-id="' + option.id + '">Remove</span></span>'
        );

        return $option;
      }

      $('#mySelect').on("select2:selecting", function (e) { 
    if (e.params.args.originalEvent.target.className === 'remove-button') {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
            
        var itemId=$(e.params.args.originalEvent.target).data("id");
            $('#mySelect').find('option[value="' + itemId + '"]').remove();
        $('#mySelect').trigger('change');
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/vsg427zj/